# Unexpected field change in firebase transaction

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting a strange update in some but not all of my data fields with a firebase transaction.

I have a tinder style app where I only look at "posts" that have a date in the future. I can see in my db that my test post has a date in the future and opens in the app. If the date is in the past it does not open as expected. My problem is that after I perform a swipe, triggering the code below, the date field seems to be updated to a semi-random date which is not the date on my computer or the device but is always the 28th of some month. As far as I can tell the code below should not be updating the date but even the log statement shows the date to have been updated

```
public void swipeReject(String postId) {
        getPostRef(postId);
        onSwiped(globalPostRef, FALSE);
    }

    private void getPostRef(String postId){
        mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        globalPostRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("messages").child(postId);
    }

    private void onSwiped(DatabaseReference postRef, Boolean accepted) {
        final Boolean accept = accepted;
        postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                PostMessage p = mutableData.getValue(PostMessage.class);
                if (p == null) {
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                Log.e("date", String.valueOf(p.getDate()));

                if (p.votes.containsKey(mFirebaseUser.getUid())) {
                    // This shouldn't happen

                } else {
                    if (accept){
                        p.votes.put(mFirebaseUser.getUid(), "upvote");
                        p.upVoteCount = p.upVoteCount + 1;
                    }else{
                        p.votes.put(mFirebaseUser.getUid(), "downvote");
                        p.downVoteCount = p.downVoteCount + 1;
                    }
                }

                // Set value and report transaction success
                mutableData.setValue(p);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                   DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Transaction completed
                if (databaseError != null){
                    Log.e(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
                }
            }
        });
```

code prior to this simply reads the data from the db with no write operations. I have no idea this field is updating?

Anything I can do to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with my code. The error was in my db values. While the Milliseconds since Epoch was correct there was also another date field that recorded the year that was not correct. Once this was updated everything made sense.